# Can't install python packages in terminal after opening Jupiter notebook

Tags: python, terminal, jupyter

I am using a macOS.

When I open a new terminal, I am able to install python packages. However, as soon as I open a Jupiter notebook from the terminal, when I run `pip install`, `brew install` or other installation methods, nothing happens.  No error message, it just no longer runs.

I don't know what other information would be helpful, but I would appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notebook server runs in foreground (as in a persistent process), so you're probably typing commands to the server application (which doesn't take any command line input) instead of to the shell. You should try entering your commands into a new shell.

Comment: That was the issue!  Thanks a lot.